# How do I select collection attributes fields in mongoose aggregation framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How to select collection attribute fields in the Mongoose aggregation framework?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

##### Data:

```js
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    name: "abc",
    question: 23,
    answers: 126
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    name: "some",
    question: 21,
    answers: 128
  }
]
```

##### Aggregation :

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      key: 1,
      name: 1
    }
  }
])
```

##### output :

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": 1,
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "key": 2,
    "name": "some"
  }
]
```